# Intellij not using attached sources?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have attached sources for the hadoop core as shown in the screenshot. But when I click into one of the core classes it still says sources are not available.

Intellij "copy location" shows the jar file for this class is the hadoop core:

```
/Users/steve/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-core/1.2.1/hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar!/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Reducer.class
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is that class actually in hadoop-core?

Comment: @jackrabbit.  double checked:  /Users/steve/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-core/1.2.1/hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar!/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Reducer.class

Comment: Looking at the source distribution, the mapreduce source is stored in a different directory than the core sources. Does that class exists inside the src jar? If not, that is probably a packaging mistake.

Comment: @jackrabbit  I updated the question showing the path for the reducer class is inside core jar file.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I can't find a src jar for hadoop-core anywhere. Did you package that yourself? That would also explain why the sources jar is not inside your maven cache.

Comment: @jackrabbit .  Yes I packaged it myself - it does not exist in maven. What does that have to do with IJ not finding the sources - which I attached myself?  Not in maven cache should not result that IJ can not find sources attached manually.

Comment: There are multiple source directories in the hadoop source distribution. I suspect that you have not included the one for mapreduce inside your sources jar.

Comment: Alright I concede. IntWritable IS in the sources. So yes there is a separate source directory for the mapred/mapreduce classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [hadoop-core source distribution](http://apache.belnet.be/hadoop/common/hadoop-1.2.1/hadoop-1.2.1.tar.gz) includes multiple source directories, and the `mapreduce` package is in a different one than most of the other packages. You appear to have forgotten to include the mapreduce source directory when you created your `hadoop-core-1.2.1-sources.jar`.